# nginx and django - gettng cache-control to work

Tags: django, nginx

I am trying to get cache-comtrol to work.

In nginx I have the following:

```
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/ubuntu/workspace/mysite;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }
```

in mysite dir I have static.  In static I have the dirs for js, css, and images.

In the web browser I get 404 error.  Images cant be found.  If I remove location /static/ this site works but I have no cache-control.

How do I resolve?

Comment: Try adding a trailing slash: alias /home/ubuntu/workspace/mysite/;

Comment: View nginx_root/logs/error.log to obtain the path that nginx tries.

Comment: I looked at the logs....yup I needed to add static do the alias.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use url like: `http://your.page.com/static/image.gif` then with your rules you get such uri (including `alias` directive):

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/mysiteimage.gif;
```

So conclusion is that remove last `/` from `location` directive (it should be `/static`) or add at the end to `alias` directive `/` (so it will be as `alias /home/ubuntu/workspace/mysite/;`)

Other solution could be like:

```
location ~ (static/.*) {
   alias /home/ubuntu/workspace/mysite/$1;
   # ... rest of code here
}
```

Then you don't have to add `static` again in `alias` directive. You just use it as location param ($1 = static/.*).

Why that way? `alias` directive ([alias doc](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias)) work as follow: it trims from requested url part matched in `location` directive end then, with what will stay, append to it own rule path. In your example from url `/static/image.gif/` it will trim `/static/` and to your `alias` path append only `image.gif` so it will look like I wrote: /home/ubuntu/workspace/mysiteimage.gif/`.